# Does $A$ being positive definite imply $\ker A = 0\,$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, inner-products, positive-definite

If $A$ is a positive definite matrix can it be concluded that the kernel of $A$ is $\{0\}$?

pf: R.T.P $\ker A = 0$.
Suppose not, i.e., there exists some $x\in\ker A$ s.t $x\neq 0$, then
$$Ax = 0\;\Longrightarrow x^T Ax = 0$$
which is a contradiction by definition of positive definite.
Therefore $\ker A=\{0\}$.

Comment: Your proof is correct

Comment: A direct proof would be noting that all the eigenvalues are strictly positive.

Comment: There is no need to prove the contrapositive: if $x\in\ker A$, then $Ax=0$ and in turn $x^TAx=0$. As $A$ is positive definite, we get $x=0$. Therefore $\ker A=0$.

Answer (score 3):

$\color{blue}{\text{user}1551}$'s comment as answer.

If $x\in\ker A$, then $Ax=0\,$ and in turn $\,x^TAx=0$. As $A$ is positive definite, we get $\,x=0$.
Therefore $\ker A=\{0\}\,$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct. As an alternative, we have a nonzero $x$ so that $Ax=0=0x$, which means $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. But the eigenvalues of a positive definite matrix are supposed to be positive, a contradiction.